# exceptionshub.com copies Stack Overflow questions verbatim and does not give credit to SO nor the users posting

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

https://exceptionshub.com/clang-format-line-breaks.html is an exact duplicate of [Clang-format line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656800/clang-format-line-breaks) when it comes to the content.